# Search file without extension in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

How can I search a specific file name without typing its file extension? For example filename `penguin-family.png` and in textbox I typed `penguin only` then it will listbox will populate files thats contains `penguin` something like this.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">

</asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button1"runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="300px"></asp:ListBox>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/files"));
        foreach (FileInfo files in folder.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(files.Name);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ListBox1.Items.Clear();
       string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/files"));

       foreach (string item in files)
       {
           string fileName = Path.GetFileName(item);
           if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower()))
           {
               ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
           }

       }
}
```

Comment: What if its inside a sub folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/files"))
                   .Where(file => file.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim()))
                   .ToArray();

     foreach (string item in files)
     {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
     }

}
```

well, you can optimized it more by using `Dictionary<string, string>` and bind directly to listbox. like this -

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/files"))
           .Where(file => file.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim()))
           .ToList();

Dictionary<string, string> fileList = files
           .Zip(files, (listText, listValue) => new { listText, listValue})
           .ToDictionary(x => x.listValue, x => x.listText);
ListBox1.DataSource = fileList;
ListBox1.DataTextField = "listValue";
ListBox1.DataValueField = "listText";
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

If you are using .Net framework 4.5 then you can use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/files"))
    .Where(file => file.ToLower().Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower().Trim()))
    .ToArray();
```